# How to enforce sub graphs to be on the same horizontal line in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm using graphviz (dot) to generate time expanded graph to use in my master thesis. However, my drawing results the following graph:
[image: Resulting Graph]

As you can see, the third line is a little bit shifted to the right.I want all the lines in the same horizontal line. Also i want the x.th node in each line to stay at the same horizontal line of other x.th nodes of lines. Changing the edge weights would not helped me.

I could not find anything related to this problem so far.

What i want to achieve is something like this: 
[image: Example Graph]

Here is my code:

```
digraph G {
1[label="1"]
2[label="1"]
3[label="1"]
4[label="1"]
5[label="1"]
6[label="1"]
7[label="2"]
8[label="2"]
9[label="2"]
10[label="2"]
11[label="2"]
12[label="2"]
13[label="3"]
14[label="3"]
15[label="3"]
16[label="3"]
17[label="3"]
18[label="3"]
19[label="4"]
20[label="4"]
21[label="4"]
22[label="4"]
23[label="4"]
24[label="4"]

rankdir="LR";
node[width=0.15, height=0.15, shape=point];
edge[weight=500, label="1"];

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 ;
7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 ;
13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 16 -> 17 -> 18 ;
19 -> 20 -> 21 -> 22 -> 23 -> 24 ;

edge[weight=3];
1 -> 9;
2 -> 9;
3 -> 11;

13 -> 22;
14 -> 22;
15 -> 24;

edge[weight=1];
1 -> 14;
2 -> 15;
3 -> 17;

7 -> 21;
8 -> 23;
9 -> 22;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `weight` try using the attribute `constraint=false` for all edges which go from one "line" to another.

Setting `constraint` to `false` makes graphviz to *not* consider those edges when laying out the nodes of the graph.

See also this [very similar question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031849/63733)

Comment: Thanks, that solved my alignment problem. But now, line two and line three swapped. I want them in order of 1,2,3,4 from top to bottom. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Some [invisible edges](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12578764/63733) usually help (some [other useful techniques here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25776916/63733)).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way is to specify an explicit position for each individual node.

See: [How to force node position (x and y) in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343899/how-to-force-node-position-x-and-y-in-graphviz)